# private class with array from database

Tags: php, arrays, class

i have private class with array :

```
class Whois{
    private $whoisServers = array(
  "ac"=> "whois.nic.ac",
  "ae" => "whois.nic.ae",
  "tech" => "whois.nic.tech",
  "yu" => "whois.ripe.net");
}
```

now, possible i get array()  for private $whoisServers from database?

Comment: You cannot access the private values of a class directly after making the object.  But for getting a private variable's value you should make a getter. I am giving an answer below. ....

Answer (score 2):

Now make an object of a class and access to public function.

```
        <?php
class Whois{

    private $whoisServers = array(
      "ac"=> "whois.nic.ac",
      "ae" => "whois.nic.ae",
      "tech" => "whois.nic.tech",
      "yu" => "whois.ripe.net");


    /*
    !----------------------------------------------
    ! Getting Private Server List Using Public Function
    ! @getter
    !----------------------------------------------
    */
    public function getWhichServers()
    {
        return $this->whoisServers;
    }

    /*
        https://github.com/arif98741
    */
}

$object     = new Whois();
$serverlist = $object->getWhichServers();
```